# Question on using BeautifulSoup library to parse data from Amazon

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I was trying to parse data from Amazon via the following page: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Apple&rh=n%3A2407749011 by using BeautifulSoup.  I was able to parse the product name, price, number of comments, but I cannot find the Brand name, Display Size, Capacity, Color in the output by using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

site = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Apple&rh=n%3A2407749011'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/47.0.2526.83'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
soup
```

I saw the following block of tags in the source code but i cannot use any .find and find_all functions to parse them out.

```
<div class="s-product-specs-view">
<div class="sg-row">
<div class="sg-col-8-of-28 sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-0-of-16 sg-col-8-of-32 sg-col sg-col-8-of-20 sg-col-8-of-36 sg-col-8-of-24"><div class="sg-col-inner">

    <div class="sg-row">

            <div class="sg-col-2-of-36 sg-col-2-of-28 sg-col-2-of-16 sg-col sg-col-2-of-32 sg-col-2-of-24 sg-col-2-of-12 sg-col-2-of-20"><div class="sg-col-inner">
                <span dir="auto">Brand</span><br/><span class="a-text-bold" dir="auto">Apple</span>
            </div></div>

            <div class="sg-col-2-of-36 sg-col-2-of-28 sg-col-2-of-16 sg-col sg-col-2-of-32 sg-col-2-of-24 sg-col-2-of-12 sg-col-2-of-20"><div class="sg-col-inner">
                <span dir="auto">Display Size</span><br/><span class="a-text-bold" dir="auto">4.7 inches</span>
            </div></div>

            <div class="sg-col-2-of-36 sg-col-2-of-28 sg-col-2-of-16 sg-col sg-col-2-of-32 sg-col-2-of-24 sg-col-2-of-12 sg-col-2-of-20"><div class="sg-col-inner">
                <span dir="auto">Capacity</span><br/><span class="a-text-bold" dir="auto">32 GB</span>
            </div></div>

            <div class="sg-col-2-of-36 sg-col-2-of-28 sg-col-2-of-16 sg-col sg-col-2-of-32 sg-col-2-of-24 sg-col-2-of-12 sg-col-2-of-20"><div class="sg-col-inner">
                <span dir="auto">Color</span><br/><span class="a-text-bold" dir="auto">Space Gray</span>
            </div></div>

    </div>

</div></div>
</div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if I missed anything in the code.  Thanks for everyone's help in advance.

Comment: The brand name is Apple :/ The capacity and colour you will have to parse yourself out of the product name (just using normal python string parsing, beautiful soup won't help you there) and the display size info literally isn't on the page so you can't scrape it without getting more info (for example, by following each link)

Comment: Those are generated by javascript. I checked myself. I am getting div part but not the content. So I guess you have to go for selenium. You can use amazon api. If I am correct then there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what kind of parser you will use in BeautifulSoup().

Change `soup = BeautifulSoup(page)` this with `soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")`

it will solve your problem

Comment: The addition of "html.parser" allowed parsing more tags, but the attributes like Brand, Capacity still do not exist.  I cross-checked it with the source code and I found that there are a lot of missing tags in my parsed data.

Comment: is there a way I can see the code you have written so far so that I can help better

Comment: That's all I have for now: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

site = 'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Apple&rh=n%3A2407749011'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/47.0.2526.83'}
req = Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
soup

Comment: I tried with soup.find('div', class_="sg-col-2-of-36 sg-col-2-of-28 sg-col-2-of-16 sg-col sg-col-2-of-32 sg-col-2-of-24 sg-col-2-of-12 sg-col-2-of-20") but it doesn't work

Comment: i think the reason why you cannot have a detailed source code is in the text you get """"To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.""""""